# The current code kills both the opened images. is it possible to kill just one?

Tags: visual-studio

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\automation\Desktop\batman1.jpg")
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\automation\Desktop\batman2.jpg")
'some timer
Process.GetProcessesByName("Microsoft.Photos")(0).Kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say. Because we don't know what exactly happens when you start a jpg. Your default application will open. And if that opens two processes or just one is something you have to ask the developer of *that* application.

In your case I guess it's "Microsoft Photos". If you look at it closely, you will see it's a single process that has 2 open windows. So killing the process will close both windows.

You could try to enumerate the windows of said process and close the one you want to close. But again, on a different computer with a different default image viewer, that will not work either.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried many ways but it always closes both of them so i guess it is the way it is..